# How should duplicated information between "new in <version>" topics and feature-specific ones be handled?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-examples

While reading through some content in the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag on Documentation, I noticed some worrying duplicated information.

In the "C# 6.0 Features" topic, [one of the examples](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/24/c-sharp-6-0-features/49/string-interpolation) is a very thorough explanation of string interpolation in C#. This example has something approximating 10 headings, and fills a large portion of the page. Meanwhile, there is [a dedicated topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/22/string-interpolation) on string interpolation, with much of the same information -- but there are some key facts (such as the specifics of the type that string interpolation produces) that are absent in the dedicated topic but explained in detail in the single separated example.

This seems wrong to me. Obviously, it's an easy fix to add the missing information into an example on the dedicated topic. But the fact that there is a more detailed explanation in the "new features" topic means that effort is duplicated and people must wade through lots of content in what I would expect should be a relatively brief overview of new features.

To make things worse, other topics link to the two aforementioned sections inconsistently. For example, the page on `String.Format` includes [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/79/string-format/6206/since-c6) which links to the interpolation section of the "New in C# 6" topic instead of the one dedicated to string interpolation.

How should situations like this be handled? It seems to me that there was something approaching community consensus that [this style of "new features" topic should not be created](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329438/should-we-be-making-documentation-topics-for-new-features-in-a-specific-language), but is the proper course of action to delete it outright and relocate that content? That seems a bit drastic given the amount of text that's in there.

Comment: On the flip side, topics which are lists of deprecated features. You can move the examples to another topic, which seems to be the preferred method of handling this type of thing.